# umano sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout for bottom slideup panel height different for different phone screen szie

Tags: android, android-xml, slideup

I am using  umano  sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout for bottom slide up layout. I have set height for the umano panel layout as 400dp which match my phone small screen and design is correct. when application is installed on large screen phones the panel height is very small compared to the design.

How to make the panel always stay below a image and while scrolling the panel should slide up

```
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="460dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="5dp"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/cl_dragged_view">
```

Answer (score 0):

calculate the height of total screen.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                activityContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                    int height1 = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

then calculate the height of the layout that the sliding panel should touch

```
 ViewTreeObserver vto = clLottiePanel.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        clLottiePanel.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        clLottiePanel.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                    int height = binding.clLottiePanel.getMeasuredHeight();
                    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    .getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                    int height1 = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                    Log.d("TAG", "onGlobalLayout: ");
                  slidingLayout.setPanelHeight(height1 - height);

                }
            });
```

now

```
sidingLayout.setPanelHeight(height1 - height);
```

this give the hieght for each screen to set for panel height.